# Python code runs in anaconda prompt but doesnt run in Windows prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, command-prompt, windows-terminal

When I run my code using anaconda with `> python main.py` it works but when I run it using windows command prompt it gives me this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

But as far as I can tell all modules are installed properly. Using python 3.8 and latest version of anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the modules are installed in your anaconda environment not windows environment so command prompt doesn't know where the modules are installed, if you need to run the code from command prompt you will need to ensure that python is correctly configured on your windows PATH and that the relevant modules are installed there as well

Comment: When i ran pip install req.txt in command prompt it showed me all requirements are satisfied. So it seems I have all the correct modules in the windows env but its still showing me same error

Comment: I ran pip install req.txt with the --force-reinstall tag and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, This maybe 2 reasons.

**Reason1 :** Libraries not installed correctly on your python pip environment.

**Reason2**: Libraries version's may different from anaconda & idle local python.

**Try following steps:**

Try finding libraries versions of anaconda & compare versions with local python libraries versions.

You can do that by

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

Similarly compare libraries versions causing issues. I previously encountered same issue. I just solved by installing same versions.